How to deserialize a field that contains JSON?
Imagine I need to parse the following body:
{
  "input": "{\"type\":\"id\",\"name\":\"DNI\"}"
}

As you can see, the input field contains a JSON but in "string".
I have the following Rust struct
pub struct Input {
  input: String
}

and then I can deserialize it, but I would like to have it defined like this:
pub struct InputType {
  type: String,
  name: String
}
pub struct Input {
  input: InputType
}

any idea how can I do it?

Use deserialize_with like so:
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct InputType {
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    typ: String,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Input {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_input")]
    input: InputType,
}

fn deserialize_input<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<InputType, D::Error> {
    let text = String::deserialize(d)?;
    serde_json::from_str(&text).map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
}

Playground

It's worth noting you can generalize this to return T where T: DeserializeOwned, allowing you to use it to deserialize any field that is encoded as a JSON string without needing a function per type. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5a89de6faaeb0beba8d3bf66fbf944c
